# How can I calculate q-value using R?

Tags: r, package

Package "qvalue" was not available for R version 3.6.1
So I installed "BiocManager" package instead, but could't find the examplary code.
Anyone have tried it? Or please tell me alternative ways to calculate q-value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you to do try to install the package? The package's github repo gives instructions for how to install it—that didn't work?

Comment: I am on R 3.6.1, BiocManager::install("qvalue"), works for me. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to install it through Github. Try this to install the qvalue package. [Github for package](https://github.com/StoreyLab/qvalue)

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("jdstorey/qvalue")
```